# Does typecasting enables the typecasted variable to use more bits than its original type can?

Tags: c++

while using this code:

```
    unsigned char c=1023;
    std::bitset <32> x((int)c);
    std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
```

the output is:

> 00000000000000000000000011111111

Why is it not using the entire 4 bytes which can be availed after typecasting (as 1023 needs 10 bits but char has only 8), I mean, in this code:

```
     char c=68;
     cout<<sizeof(c)<<endl<<sizeof((int) c)<<endl;
```

the output is:

> 1
>
> 4

If after typecasting the size changes then why it can't avail more bits?

Comment: What did you expect initializing a *byte* to `1023`  would do? Where do you think the extra two bits would be stored?

Comment: My compiler says *"error : implicit conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char' changes value from 1023 to 255"* After that you will never get the original value back.

Comment: @BoPersson: Is it standard conforming behavior? Maybe not. The program is not ill formed, so the compiler should compile it.

Comment: @underscore_d: why? Is it a badly written question? A beginner can ask something like this. What is obvious for you, maybe not obvious for someone else.

Comment: @geza - The error might turn into a warning with weaker compiler options. I just don't like that.

Answer (score 1):

What does your code do (I suppose that `unsigned char` is a 8-bit type)?

```
unsigned char c=1023;
```

Here, as `unsigned char` is 8-bit, 1023 doesn't fit. So, according to the standard `c` value will be 1023 modulo 256 = 255 (i.e., the highest 2 bits of 1023 are lost).

```
std::bitset <32> x((int)c);
```

Here, you cast `c` to `int`. Note, that here **`c` doesn't "get back" its lost bits**, so the cast result will be 255.

And of course, the cout will print 255 in binary, that's what you got.

Comment: the entire confusion is due to the sizeof(int) - I was thinking that if it is showing 4 bytes then it must have devoted 4 bytes for the typecasted variable c & this modulo operation wouldn't take place, i.e. the 10 bits will be set in the newly available bits after telecasting to represent 1023.

Comment: @Gaurav: no. at the `c=1023` line, information has been lost, there is no way to get it back. If you don't like this, use `int c = 1023;`. If you want to store a 10-bit value, then you need to use a type which can store it.

Comment: now I have used
        int i=1023;
        std::bitset <32> x((unsigned char)i);
        std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
even now the modulo operation has taken place despite using int. now it displays only 8 bits.

Comment: @Gaurav: why do you cast to `i` to `unsigned char`? That's the operation which truncates the value to 8 bits. Remove it, and you'll find your 10-bit value intact.

Comment: sorry for asking too many stupid questions but can typecasting only truncate?

Comment: @Gaurav: I don't really understand your question. If the target type is shorter then the source type, then there will be truncation (if the target type is unsigned).